# "Android SDK Errors" Error parsing XML: Not well formed

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android SDK and getting these two errors, PLEASE help!!
- The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed
- Error parsing XML: Not well formed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:angle="270"
    android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
    android:endColor="#24b2eb"
    android:startColor="#24b2eb" />

<corners
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:radius="5dp" />

</shape><LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it was usefull :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to have something order the objects so all your objects have to be encapsulated in one layout object.

Answer (score 0):

XML files have to have one root element that all other views fit into. That means that whichever  tag is at the top must not be closed  until the bottom.

In your xml file, you want LinearLayout to be the root element. But you (probably by accident) closed it right after you opened it.

Do this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:angle="270"
    android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
    android:endColor="#24b2eb"
    android:startColor="#24b2eb" />

<corners
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>

</LinearLayout>
```